# Cannot pass list as API Method parameter: JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] out of VALUE_STRING token

Tags: java, android, jackson, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

I'm defining a Google Cloud endpoint as:

```
@ApiMethod(
        name = "list",
        path = "MyUser",
        httpMethod = ApiMethod.HttpMethod.GET)
public CollectionResponse<MyUser> list(@Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursor, @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit, @Named("phones") ArrayList<String> phones) {
....
```

And calling it from the android client like this:

```
myUserApi.list(phones).execute();
```

But i get the following exception:

```
 {
"code": 400,
"errors": [
{
"domain": "global",
"message": "com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] out of VALUE_STRING token\n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]",
"reason": "badRequest"
}
],
"message": "com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] out of VALUE_STRING token\n at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]"
}
```

I don't know what's the problem. According to the official Cloud Endpoints documentation, List parameters are valid.

Edit: this is the debug message from the cloud console:

```
Request URL: https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/api/myUserApi/v1/myUserphones?phones=11111111&phones=222222222&phones=3333333&phones....
Method: myUserApi.list
Error Code: 400
Reason: badRequest
Message: com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String[] out of VALUE_STRING token
```

Apparently, it's converting each of the elements in the list into a parameter instead of passing everything as an array. How do i fix this?

Comment: Could you post some code showing how 'phones' is defined on the Android client?

Comment: Phones is defined as ArrayList<String>. In the backend i defined it as a String[] but the autogenerated code for the client requires a List.